# Add a constraint from a point A to another constraint in Matter.js

Tags: javascript, matter.js

```js
let Engine = Matter.Engine,
  Render = Matter.Render,
  Runner = Matter.Runner,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
  Constraint = Matter.Constraint;

let engine = Engine.create(),
  world = engine.world;

let render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    wireframes: false,
    background: "#fafafa",
  },
});

let base = Bodies.rectangle(400, 100, 350, 20, {
  isStatic: true,
  render: { fillStyle: "#2e3276" },
});

let side_base = Bodies.rectangle(280, 280, 20, 350, {
  isStatic: true,
  render: { fillStyle: "#2e3276" },
});

let ball = Bodies.circle(800, 300, 20, {
  density: 0.04,
  frictionAir: 0.005,
  restitution: 0.8,
  friction: 0.01,
  render: { fillStyle: "#4CAF50" },
});

let pendulum = Constraint.create({
  pointA: { x: 400, y: 100 },
  bodyB: ball,
  render: { strokeStyle: "#000000" },
  length: 170,
});

let spring = Constraint.create({
  pointA: { x: 280, y: 300 },
  bodyB: ball,
  stiffness: 0.0001,
  render: { strokeStyle: "#000000" },
});

World.add(world, [base, side_base, ball, pendulum, spring]);
Runner.run(engine);
Render.run(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/matter-js@0.18.0/build/matter.min.js"></script>
```

Example, first, I have a rectangle and a circle. I created a contraint from rectangle to circle and it worked and it's like a Pendulum. Now I need to create a new constraint from another rectangle to the constraint before created, but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea about the problem? Thanks. This problem was made in matter.js

[pendulum with a spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8571B.jpg)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xpxg.jpg)

It's like that, but I need the spring in the line, not in the circle.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. That said, I don't really understand the question/problem. Your code seems working. Where is the new constraint you're trying to add? What "doesn't work" exactly?

Comment: I need the spring that is in the left rectangle to be in the middle of the pendulum string, I mean, point A is in the middle of the left rectangle and point B is on the pendulum string, that's the problem. The constraint (line) between the top rectangle and the circle isn't a body.

Comment: @Hasam in other words, you want the left string to connect to the middle of the top string, right?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the goal. WOWOW's guess seems pretty good though. Waiting for OP confirmation. If that's the case, you could make a hidden, non-colliding static body and position it halfway between the two points on the top constraint, then manually position it on every frame and use it as the endpoint of the left constraint.

Comment: That's correct, but I also need it to act like a spring when it moves to represent the elasticity constant. I'm going to try to put an image.

Comment: I put an example of the exercise.

Comment: Is constraint K always horizontal, and it slides along the vertical line, or is constraint K always attached to a single point that can move up and down?

Comment: K is horizontal and it slides along the vertical line, but it just do the function of a spring, stop the movement with its stiffness.

Comment: I think the request is totally clear to me now. I'll add an answer when I can, but I think the solution would be something similar to what I described above, except you'd need to compute the intersection point of the horizontal K spring and the line from the ball to the top bar. Wherever that intersection is on each frame is where you'd position the invisible constraint body (probably in `beforeUpdate`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like the goal is for the constraint K to remain horizontal and move up and down line L, connecting at whatever x point K and L intersect.

One approach is to compute the x-intercept of L, then position an invisible, non-colliding body there on every frame. The invisible body will be constraint K's endpoint.

```js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();

const render = Matter.Render.create({
  engine,
  element: document.body,
  options: {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    wireframes: false,
    background: "#fafafa",
  },
});

const base = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 100, 350, 20, {
  isStatic: true,
  render: {fillStyle: "#2e3276"},
});

const sideBase = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(280, 280, 20, 350, {
  isStatic: true,
  render: {fillStyle: "#2e3276"},
});

const ball = Matter.Bodies.circle(300, 300, 20, {
  density: 0.04,
  frictionAir: 0.005,
  restitution: 0.8,
  friction: 0.01,
  render: {fillStyle: "#4CAF50"},
});

const pendulum = Matter.Constraint.create({
  pointA: {x: 400, y: 100},
  bodyB: ball,
  render: {strokeStyle: "#000000"},
  length: 170,
});

const lineAnchor = Matter.Bodies.circle(0, 0, 0, {
  isStatic: true,
  isSensor: true,
});

const spring = Matter.Constraint.create({
  pointA: {x: 280, y: 200},
  bodyB: lineAnchor,
  stiffness: 0.0001,
  render: {strokeStyle: "#000000"},
});

Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, [
  base,
  sideBase,
  ball,
  pendulum,
  spring,
  lineAnchor,
]);
Matter.Runner.run(engine);
Matter.Render.run(render);

const findXCoordinate = (x1, y1, x2, y2, y) => {
  // slope
  const m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);

  // y-intercept (b)
  const b = y1 - m * x1;

  // x-coordinate when the line passes through y
  const x = (y - b) / m;
  return x;
};

Matter.Events.on(engine, "afterUpdate", () => {
  const {x: x1, y: y1} = ball.position;
  const {x: x2, y: y2} = pendulum.pointA;
  const {y} = spring.pointA;
  const x = findXCoordinate(x1, y1, x2, y2, y);
  Matter.Body.setPosition(lineAnchor, {x, y});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/matter-js@0.19.0/build/matter.min.js"></script>
```

The (possible) problem here is that the constraint K doesn't exert any force on the pendulum line L because `setPosition` overrides physics. This seems to be the desired behavior, given that the constraint's stiffness is so low.

If this isn't the intent, it seems a bit contrary to the constraint being purely horizontal--I would pick a fixed point on the line and tie the constraint to it, probably splitting the line into two parts joined by a body. This way, if the ball is pulled hard by the horizontal constraint, the bottom part below the connecting point will droop naturally (or, make the bottom body attached on a rigid constraint if that's not desired).

Another option is to keep your original design with a constraint linked to the ball, but make this constraint invisible. Then use my horizontal constraint above to add the desired visible effect. Ultimately, the behavior won't be physically perfect, since the L constraint will be pulling on the ball rather than the chain, but may be close enough to create the necessary illusion for your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much @ggorlen and I'm sorry for take your time. Have a good day